# Font's with inbuilt extra padding

Tags: css, google-fonts

I am using a Google Font: Baloo Bhaina and despite setting margin and padding to zero, it still seems to be double height.

[image: Screeb of font highlighted showing extra space]

As you can see, highlighting the font shows the extra space that I can't get rid of. Anyone come across this before? Google fonts are usually awesome to work with.

Class attached to this font:

```
.hero-element h2 {
font-size: 5vw;
font-family: $brand-font;
color: $brand-color;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `line-height: 1`

Comment: Set your line-height to zero. `line-height:1;`

Comment: From looking at it at the Googlefonts website, it seems this font really occupies a lot of blank space below the regular letters - but I think you won't be able to change that. Maybe that has to do with the characters for Indian languages it also includes (but which are not visible at the Googlefonts page) - just a guess...

Comment: Thanks guys but I already tried line-height:1; - didn't work. Really surprised that Google have included such a difficult to work with font in their catalogue.

Comment: I ran into this same issue. I really like the font style! It's so crisp and readable but the amount of vertical space the letters and numbers occupy is completely unnecessary. For what it's worth Baloo Paaji 2 is a very similar font, and while it still has the vertical issue, it's not as bad as Baloo Bhaina.